# ItemClick on Fragment makes the android App crash

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to show that when an item is clicked on an item on one fragement- details of that item is shown on the other fragment. It seems my code has no error. However , whenever I click on an item,the android app crashes and closes down.

Below  is my COMPLETE(100%) code for all activities and corresponding xml files. You can simply copy these codes and run. I am not being able to find out why is it that the app crashes each time an item is clicked.

Error LogCat:

```
2022-04-17 19:18:09.220 8609-8609/com.example.fragment D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-04-17 19:18:09.222 8609-8609/com.example.fragment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fragment, PID: 8609
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.fragment.MainActivity.OnItemSelected(MainActivity.java:32)
        at com.example.fragment.ListFrag.onListItemClick(ListFrag.java:56)
        at androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:64)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1187)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3179)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4097)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2022-04-17 19:18:09.249 8609-8609/com.example.fragment I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8609 SIG: 9
```

MainActivity.java

package com.example.fragment;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListFrag.ItemSelected {
  TextView tvDescrtiption;
    ArrayList<String> descriptions;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvDescrtiption=findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);

        descriptions=new ArrayList<String>();

        descriptions.add("Descriptions for Item 1");
        descriptions.add("Descriptions for Item 2");
        descriptions.add("Descriptions for Item 3");

    }

    public void OnItemSelected(int index) {
        tvDescrtiption.setText(descriptions.get(index));

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="com.example.fragment.ListFrag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView2"
        android:name="com.example.fragment.Detail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ListFrag.java

```
package com.example.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment;


import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListFrag extends ListFragment {
    ItemSelected activity;
public interface ItemSelected
{
    void OnItemSelected(int index);
}

    public ListFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        activity=(ItemSelected) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<String> data= new ArrayList<>();
        data.add("1. This is Item 1");
        data.add("2. This is Item 2");
        data.add("3. This is Item 3");

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data));

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick( ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    
        activity.OnItemSelected(position);
    }
}
```

fragment_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ListFrag">

    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/lvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Detail.java

```
package com.example.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Detail extends Fragment {
    
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    public Detail() {
       
    }

   
    public static Detail newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Detail fragment = new Detail();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    tools:context=".Detail">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash. If you do not understand the stack trace, edit your question and post the stack trace.

Comment: yes, I edited question and posted the Log Cat output to show where it is failing- it is saying a null object reference on setText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution I was looking for

I just added the following code in my MainActivity.java

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tvDescrtiption=findViewById(R.id.tvDescription );
    }
```

Now, using onPostCreate ,I can refer to tvDescriptions from another Layout, it this is no more considered as null value.

Answer (score 1):

*tvDescrtiption* is null because it's inside a Detail fragment not directly in MainActivity, you should try and update the fragment from within.

Comment: The detail is inside Main Activity, you can see here under the component tree, i shared the screenshot https://prnt.sc/JW6v2SCMznQk

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a `NullPointerException` because when `.setText()` is invoked, it is being invoked on `tvDescrtiption`, which is null. If you set a breakpoint on lines 19 (`tvDescrtiption=findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);`) and 30 (`tvDescrtiption.setText(descriptions.get(index));`), you will see that `tvDescrtiption` is indeed null.

Why is it null? I have not used `findViewById()` in the longest, but if I recall correctly, you can only retrieve a `View` this way if you inflated it in the `Activity` or `Fragment`. `tvDescrtiption` lives in `fragment_detail.xml`, but in `MainActivity`, you are inflating `activity_main.xml`. You can currently only use `findViewById()` in `MainActivity` to retrieve views declared in `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: I don't believe you would. If you are wanting to update a fragment, you should be doing it within the fragment class. It does not make sense to update it in the parent activity. Move your onClick and the data into the appropriate fragments.